# Change Label of "Convert" button in lead

Tags: leads

I want to change the label of "convert" button on a lead object.

Comment: Welcome to sfse, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include the relevant code (preferable, minimal reproducible code sample) and a clear description of the problem alongside any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce did not allow you to change the level of Lead Convert button.
If you want, then you have to create custom lead convert functionality and a custom button.